# How to use concerns in routes ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have `resources :subjects` in my routes which I wants to use as optional routes by using concern.

The idea is to use DRY approach so I do not need to re-write routes lines for other case in which I do not need `resources :subjects`.

The links are like below and it is clear I have no subject_id in 2nd case as I do not need it:

```
http://localhost:3000/teacher/katherine-fleming/subjects/3/lesson_plans/3
```

and

```
http://localhost:3000/teacher/carmel-cynthia/lesson_plans/3
```

Right now, it stops working for both cases and saying:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/teacher
/katherine-fleming/subjects/3/lesson_plans/3"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/teacher/carmel-
cynthia/lesson_plans/68"):
```

My routes for case 1 are:

```
resources :subjects do
              concern :lesson_plans, :except => [:index] do
              resources :lesson_plan_registrations
              resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
              end 
 end
```

I am trying to make them working using below code but its not working as expected.

```
resources :lesson_plans, concerns: :lesson_plans
```

What's working right now is:

```
resources :subjects do
              resources :lesson_plans, :except => [:index] do
              resources :lesson_plan_registrations
              resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
              end 
 end
              resources :lesson_plans, :except => [:index] do
              resources :lesson_plan_registrations
              resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
              end
```

But its something to re-write the whole code again for the case in which I do not need `resources :subjects`.

I want to use DRY approach so it will work for both cases.

Here are full routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations', :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}

  resources :requested_schools, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :tags, only: :index
  resources :specializations, only: :index

  resources :search, only: :index
  get '/fetch_schools' => 'search#fetch_schools'
  get '/fetch_subjects' => 'search#fetch_subjects'

  resources :search_results do
    collection do
      get '/lesson_plan' => 'search_results#lesson_plan', as: :lesson_plan
      get '/video' => 'search_results#video', as: :video
      get '/document' => 'search_results#document', as: :document
      get '/note' => 'search_results#note', as: :note
    end
  end

  namespace :admin do
    root 'dashboard#index'
    get 'login' => 'sessions#new', as: :login
    resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
    resources :requested_schools, only: [:index, :edit, :edit, :show, :destroy] do
      member do
        get :accept_request
        get :decline_request
        get 'view_files' => 'requested_schools#view_files', as: :view_files
        get 'imported_data' => 'requested_schools#imported_data', as: :imported_data
      end
    end
    resource :users, :except => [:show, :index, :new, :create] do
      member do
        get :change_password
        patch :update_password
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :school do
    root 'dashboard#index'
    resources :dashboard, :path => '/', only: [:index]
    resources :departments do
      resources :subjects
    end
    resources :class_rooms do
      resources :class_room_subjects
      resources :class_room_schedules
      resources :class_room_registrations do
        collection do
          post "/student_registration" => "class_room_registrations#student_registration", as: :student_registration
        end
      end
    end
    get '/fetch_subject_teachers' => 'class_room_subjects#fetch_subject_teachers', as: :fetch_subject_teachers
    resources :schools, :path => '/', only: [:index, :edit, :show, :destroy, :update] do
      collection do
        get :change_password
        patch :update_password
        get :edit_profile
        patch :update_profile
        get :listing
        get :view_ids
        match "/upload_ids" => "schools#upload_ids", via: [:get, :post]
        get :autocomplete_school_name
        get '/view_lesson_plan/:id' => "schools#view_lesson_plan", as: :view_lesson_plan
      end
      member do
        get :students
        get :teachers
        get :lesson_plans
        match '/class_rooms' => "class_rooms#index", via: [:get, :post]
      end
    end
  end

  resources :friend_requests do
    member do
      get '/send_friend_request/:type' => "friend_requests#send_friend_request", as: :send_friend_request
      get '/decline_friend_request/:type' => "friend_requests#decline_friend_request", as: :decline_friend_request
      get '/accept_friend_request/:type' => "friend_requests#accept_friend_request", as: :accept_friend_request
      get '/cancel_friend_request/:type' => "friend_requests#cancel_friend_request", as: :cancel_friend_request
      get '/unfriend' => "friend_requests#unfriend", as: :unfriend
    end
    collection do
      get :friend_requests
    end
  end

  namespace :student do
    resources :students, :path => '/' do
      member do
        get :friends
        get :lesson_plan_progress
        post "/join_private_school/:school_id" => "students#join_private_school", as: :join_private_school
        get "/private_schools" => "students#private_schools", as: :private_schools
      end
      collection do
        get :departments
        post :select_departments
        get :list_departments
        get :my_lesson_plan
        get :special_lesson_plans
      end
      get '/view_result/:id' => "students#view_result", as: :view_result
      get '/lesson_plan/:id' => "students#lesson_plan", as: :lesson_plan
      get '/video/:id' => "students#video", as: :video
      post '/video_comments/:id' => "students#video_comments", as: :video_comments
      get '/like_video/:id' => "students#like_video", as: :like_video
      get '/liked_video_users/:id' => "students#liked_video_users", as: :liked_video_users
      get '/is_video_completed' => "students#is_video_completed", as: :is_video_completed
      get '/assignment_result/:id' => "students#assignment_result", as: :assignment_result
    end
    resource :users, :except => [:show, :index, :new, :create] do
      member do
        get :change_password
        patch :update_password
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :teacher do
    resources :teachers, :path => '/' do
      resources :subjects do
        resources :lesson_plans, :except => [:index] do
          member do
            get '/change_public' => "lesson_plans#change_public", as: :change_public
            get '/change_private' => "lesson_plans#change_private", as: :change_private
            post '/copy_lesson_plan' => "lesson_plans#copy_lesson_plan", as: :copy_lesson_plan
            get '/play_list_progress' => "lesson_plans#list_play_list_progress", as: :list_play_list_progress
          end
          resources :lesson_plan_registrations, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
          post '/move_up_down_play_list' => 'lesson_plans#move_up_down_play_list', as: :move_up_down_play_list
          resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
          resources :videos do
            member do
              get '/like_video' => "videos#like_video", as: :like_video
              get '/liked_video_users' => "videos#liked_video_users", as: :liked_video_users
              get '/delete_video_comment' => "videos#delete_video_comment", as: :delete_video_comment
              get '/is_video_completed' => "videos#is_video_completed", as: :is_video_completed
              post '/copy_video' => "videos#copy_video", as: :copy_video
            end
          end
          resources :documents do
            member do
              get '/download_file' => "documents#download_file", as: :download_file
              get '/like_document' => "documents#like_document", as: :like_document
              get '/liked_document_users' => "documents#liked_document_users", as: :liked_document_users
              post '/copy_document' => "documents#copy_document", as: :copy_document
            end
          end
          resources :notes do
            member do
              get '/like_note' => "notes#like_note", as: :like_note
              get '/liked_note_users' => "notes#liked_note_users", as: :liked_note_users
            end
          end
          resources :quizzes do
            member do
              get '/like_quiz' => "quizzes#like_quiz", as: :like_quiz
              get '/liked_quiz_users' => "quizzes#liked_quiz_users", as: :liked_quiz_users
              match '/change_public' => "quizzes#change_public", as: :change_public, via: [:get, :post]
              get '/give_quiz' => "quizzes#give_quiz", as: :give_quiz
              get '/preview_quiz' => "quizzes#preview_quiz", as: :preview_quiz
              post '/copy_quiz' => "quizzes#copy_quiz", as: :copy_quiz
            end
            resources :questions do
              collection do
                get '/fetch_question_options' => 'questions#fetch_question_options'
                match '/search_questions' => 'questions#search_questions', as: :search_questions, via: [:get, :post]
                post '/select_questions' => 'questions#select_questions', as: :select_questions
              end
            end
            resources :question_groups
            resources :sort_questions, only: [:index]
            post '/move_up_down' => 'sort_questions#move_up_down', as: :move_up_down
            resources :quiz_answers, only: [:new, :create]
            resources :quiz_attempts do
              member do
                get '/download_file' => "quiz_attempts#download_file", as: :download_file
              end
            end
          end
          resources :question_banks do
            member do
              get :fetch_picks
            end
            resources :sort_questions, only: [:index]
            resources :questions do
              member do
                post :move
              end
              collection do
                get '/fetch_question_options' => 'questions#fetch_question_options'
              end
            end
          end
          resources :assignments do
            member do
              match '/change_public' => "assignments#change_public", as: :change_public, via: [:get, :post]
              get '/like_assignment' => "assignments#like_assignment", as: :like_assignment
              get '/liked_assignment_users' => "assignments#liked_assignment_users", as: :liked_assignment_users
              get '/download_file' => "assignments#download_file", as: :download_file
              post '/copy_assignment' => "assignments#copy_assignment", as: :copy_assignment
            end
            resources :assignment_submissions do
              member do
                get '/download_file' => "assignment_submissions#download_file", as: :download_file
                post '/mark_assignment' => "assignment_submissions#mark_assignment", as: :mark_assignment
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
      resources :lesson_plans do
        resources :videos
        resources :documents
        resources :notes
        resources :quizzes do
          member do
            match '/change_public' => "quizzes#change_public", as: :change_public, via: [:get, :post]
            get '/preview_quiz' => "quizzes#preview_quiz", as: :preview_quiz
          end
          resources :questions
          resources :quiz_attempts do
            member do
              get '/download_file' => "quiz_attempts#download_file", as: :download_file
            end
          end
        end
        resources :question_banks
        resources :assignments
      end
      resources :class_rooms, :only => [:index] do
        resources :subjects do
          resources :subject_grades, only: [:index] do
            collection do
              get "/mark_complete" => "subject_grades#mark_complete", as: :mark_complete
            end
          end
          resources :class_room_subjects, only: [:update]
          resources :lessons do
            resources :attendances, only: [:index]
          end
        end
      end
      resources :private_schools do
        resources :invitation_promo_codes
        resources :private_classes do
          member do
            get :new_private_lesson_plan
            post :create_private_lesson_plan
            get "/edit_private_lesson_plan/:private_lesson_plan_id" => "private_classes#edit_private_lesson_plan", as: :edit_private_lesson_plan
            post "/update_private_lesson_plan/:private_lesson_plan_id" => "private_classes#update_private_lesson_plan", as: :update_private_lesson_plan
            get "/destroy_private_lesson_plan/:private_lesson_plan_id" => "private_classes#destroy_private_lesson_plan", as: :destroy_private_lesson_plan
          end
        end
      end
      member do
        get :friends
        get '/lesson_plans' => "lesson_plans#index", as: :lesson_plans
        get '/my_class_rooms' => "class_rooms#index", as: :my_class_rooms
        get :new_promo_code
        post :create_promo_code
        post :leave_private_school
      end
      collection do
        get :departments
        post :select_departments
        get '/:teacher_id/invitation_promo_codes' => "invitation_promo_codes#index", as: :invitation_promo_codes
      end
    end
    resource :users, :except => [:show, :index, :new, :create] do
      member do
        get :change_password
        patch :update_password
      end
    end
  end
  get '/notifications' => 'users#notifications', as: :notifications
  delete '/delete_notification/:id' => 'users#delete_notification', as: :delete_notification
  get '/notification_status' => 'users#notification_status'
end
```

Comment: can you show your full `routes.rb`?

Comment: @ThanhHuynh I have added `routes.rb` file content. Could you please review it. Thanks.

Comment: can you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your routes:

```
def lesson_plans
  resources :lesson_plans, :except => [:index] do
    resources :lesson_plan_registrations
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end 
end

resources :subjects do
  lesson_plans
end

lesson_plans
```

Comment: My God...... :) Awesome.... I can't believe how easy it was.... :) You really made my day..... :) Thank you so much.....
How did you do that? Any guide on ruby doc?

Comment: Yes, it is but I didn't know that we might write method in the route file so I just asked that. :)

Comment: @LearningROR `routes.rb` is just a Ruby file so we can write Ruby code :)

Answer (score 2):

Better way,

```
concern :lesson_plans do
  resources :lesson_plans, :except => [:index] do
    resources :lesson_plan_registrations
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end 
end

resources :subjects do
  concerns :lesson_plans
end

concerns :lesson_plans
```

Comment: Using route `concerns` is a better way to DRY duplicate routes. REF: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns